# How can I use a config json file in React with where condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, web-config

I have a json file called config.json:

```
[
  {
    "id":8,
    "data":["student","teacher"]
   },
   {
    "id":9,
    "data":["student"]
   },
   {
    "id":10,
    "data":["student","teacher","parents"]
   }
]
```

table.js:

```
import configData from "../config/config.json";
const data =configData.map(configData, 8);
console.log(data );
```

how can i read data from json when id=8 using reactjs.I tried above but showing error.

config file is a local components inside the project.

Comment: you could do `configData.filter(id=> id===8)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter or find method:
with filter method:

```js
import configData from "../config/config.json";
const data = configData.filter(function(item) {
  return item.id ===9
});

//or using ES6 you can do
const data = configData.filter(item => item.id ===9);

console.log(data );
```

or if you want a single object not an array you can use find method:

```js
import configData from "../config/config.json";
const data = configData.find(item => item.id ===9); //this will return a single object

console.log(data );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import configData from "../config/config.json";

const data = configData.find(x => x.id === 8)
```

This finds you the required data element within your configData with id = 8, and stores it in data